# What does the notation in Nash Equilibrium definition mean?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I know that the Nash equilibrium is state from which if a player will think of moving to another choice he will be not benefited. But what the following notation mean?
(Note—I am finding Game Theory notations little difficult so i want explanation with some example.)

> *DEFINITION 14.1.*
>   A **Nash equilibrium of a strategic game** $\langle N, (A_i), (\succsim_i) \rangle$ is a profile $a^* \in A$ of actions with the property that for every player $i \in N$ we have
>   $$
>   (a^*_{-i}, a^*_i) \succsim_i (a^*_{-i}, a_i)
>   \qquad
>   \text{for all $a_i \in A_i$}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by0UL.png).)

Comment: $a_{-i}^*$ is a profile of actions in Nash equilibrium of $n-1$ players which are different from player $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's unwrap the notation. *(In what I follow, I use "strategy" for "profile" when referring to the tuple of strategies of the $n$ players. I have seen used both interchangeably.)*

- For $1\leq i\leq n$, $A_i$ is the set of possible actions/strategies for player $i$. Thus, a strategy $a$ belongs to the set $A_1\times A_2\times\dots\times A_n$.
- For two strategies $a,b$ of $n$ players, and $1\leq i\leq n$
  $$
  a \gtrsim_i b
  $$
  means that the payoff for player $i$ is greater or equal under strategy $a$ than under strategy $b$.
- A game is given by a triple $(N, (A_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}, (\gtrsim_i)_{1\leq i\leq n})$ which specifies the players, the possible strategies for each of them, and the preference relations between those strategies for each player.
- By convenient, given a strategy $a = (a_1,\dots, a_{i-1}, a_i, a_{i+1}, a_n)$ and an index $i$, we write $a_{-i}$ for the "substrategy" 
  $$
  a_{-i} = (a_1,\dots, a_{i-1}, a_{i+1}, a_n)
  $$
  i.e., "the same thing without the strategy $a_i$ of the $i$-th player"; and given a replacing strategy $\alpha\in A_i$ for this player,
  $$( a_{-i}, \alpha) = (a_1,\dots, a_{i-1},\alpha, a_{i+1}, a_n)$$
  denotes the strategy obtained by replacing, in $a$, the strategy $a_i$ of the $i$-th player by an alternative strategy $\alpha$ (and keeping all the other players' strategies unchanged).

Thus, writing (for $i,a,a^\ast$ as defined in the statement)
$$
(a^\ast_{-i}, a^\ast_i) \gtrsim_i (a^\ast_{-i}, a_i) \tag{1}
$$
is exactly the same as writing
$$
a^\ast \gtrsim_i (a^\ast_{-i}, a_i) \tag{2}
$$
and means that, if every player conforms to strategy $a^\ast$, the $i$-th player  gains nothing by changing unilaterally their strategy from $a^\ast_i$ to $a_i$ *(again, while all $j\neq i$ keep their strategy $a^\ast_j$)*, as doing so will not increase player $i$-th payoff.

Comment: Really helpful answer , but i have little more confusion . If you explain your answer with a help of a example , like prisoners dilemma , in which you explain what values correspond to a particular set , then it will be very helpful .

Comment: @neraj Well, in the [Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma) (for the example, let's restrict ourselves to deterministic strategies) you have $n=2$, $A_1=A_2=\{\text{cooperate},\text{defect}\}$. The ranking functions are given  by $(\text{defects},\text{cooperate}) \gtrsim_1 (\text{cooperate},\text{cooperate})$, $(\text{cooperate},\text{cooperate}) \gtrsim_1 (\text{defects},\text{defects})$, etc. (and similar for $ \gtrsim_2$).

Comment: @neraj We have that $(coop,coop)$ cannot be a NE since, say for player 1, $(coop,coop)\not\succsim_1(def,coop)$. Check that $(coop,def)$ and $(def,coop)$ are not NEs, and that $(def,def)$ is a NE.